# Gwt visualization: graphs overlapping

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

my code is the following

```
onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    pie = new PieChart(createTable(), pieOptions());
    pie.addSelectHandler(createSelectHandler(pie));
    vstack.addMember(pie);

    barChart = new BarChart(createTable(), barOptions());
    vstack.addMember(barChart);
  }
}; 

VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(getView().getCallBack(), CoreChart.PACKAGE);
```

I'm using SmartGWT and the stack mentioned there is a VStack, but the second graph renders on top of the first one, they only display properly after I resize the browser window manually.

Has someone experienced the same?

UPDATE: here is the image (didn't notice I could add one)

[image: Overlapped graphs]

I believe is the fact that the images are loaded through the Runnable call, because as I mentioned before, once they are fully loaded you can resize the window and it fixes itself.

I'm not the only one using more than 2 graphs in one page I assume, how you guys make it work?

Comment: can you provide an image of your result?

Comment: Added a screenshot of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to why this happens to SmartGWT I still have no answer, I added an spacer between graphs and the second graph overlaps over the spacer, it is like Runnable generated widgets are fully drawn when the Layouts arrange the items.

I had to use an HTMLPanel and assign each graph widget to a div, which defeats the purpose of SmartGWT and Layouts, but was the only way it worked